# How do I force Office Communicator to open new conversations on my primary desktop?

Tags: office-communicator-2007

I am frequently logged into several computers, via remote desktop connections, with the same account that I have used to log onto my computer. When this is the case, conversation invitation notifications from Office Communicator 2007 are received in the most recently logged-in remote desktop instance. As this is often minimised or hidden behind other windows, it can often be a long time before I see the requests.

Is there a way to ensure that the invitation request notifications are shown on my main computer desktop, rather than in the remote desktop windows?

Comment: Just disable Office Communicator on this sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signing out of Communicator in the remote windows works. Had assumed this would sign me out everywhere, but it doesn't